# Changing text color when pushing button - using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, textcolor

I barely started learning javascript today, and I'm trying to change the text "Date" color from white to pink with the Surprise button, but nothing seems to work. All the other buttons work fine. (I can set the text color to white w/CSS, dunno if that got in the way but still nothing happened with the pink).

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click",
  function() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "400px";
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = "400px";
  }
);

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click",
  function() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }
);


document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click",
  function() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = ".5";
  }
);


document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click",
  function() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "150px";
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = "150px";
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = "100";
  }
);

document.getElementById("button5").addEventListener("click",
  function() {
    document.getElementById("Date").style.fontcolor = "pink";
  }
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<head>
  <title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
</head>

<body>

  <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

  <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

  <button id="button1">Grow</button>
  <button id="button2">Blue</button>
  <button id="button3">Fade</button>
  <button id="button4">Reset</button>
  <button id="button5">Surprise</button>

  <br>

  <p class="Date">Date</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to use `color`, rather than `fontcolor` which itself would be `fontColor` given the usual camel casing rules of JavaScript. Best of luck learning JavaScript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property to change font color is `style.color` and not `style.fontcolor`. And you are getting the date by using `document.getElementById('Date')` while in the `p` tag  the `class` is Date and not the `Id`

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click",
  function() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "400px";
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = "400px";
  }
);

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click",
  function() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }
);


document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click",
  function() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = ".5";
  }
);


document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click",
  function() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "150px";
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = "150px";
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = "100";
  }
);

document.getElementById("button5").addEventListener("click",
  function() {
    document.getElementById("Date").style.color = "pink";
  }
);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<head>
  <title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
</head>

<body>

  <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

  <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

  <button id="button1">Grow</button>
  <button id="button2">Blue</button>
  <button id="button3">Fade</button>
  <button id="button4">Reset</button>
  <button id="button5">Surprise</button>

  <br>

  <p id="Date">Date</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! That made it pink! 
So is there a way to start the text as white and change to pink with the button?

Answer (score 0):

Use style.color instead of style.fontColor.

```
document.getElementById('Date').style.color = 'pink'
```